# Finding the parameters (n,c) and (N,n,c) in single sampling plans

Tags: sampling, quality-control

I'm learning about devising single sampling plans for quality control, and I'd like to learn how to solve for the key parameters.  Specifically, I have two related questions.  Suppose my boss specifies the quantities \alpha (the producer's risk), \beta (the consumer's risk), p_1 (the acceptable quality level), and p_2 (the lot tolerance percent defective).

My first question is then, supposing I make a binomial approximation to the distribution of defective items, how do I choose (n,c) such that my sampling plan meets the quartet of requirements (\alpha, \beta, p_1, p_2)?

My second question is then, if I am in a regime where I have small lot sizes and the binomial approximation is then no longer valid, how do I solve for (N,n,c) in the hypergeometric model for the distribution of defects, again given the quartet (\alpha, \beta, p_1, p_2)?

I'd like to implement the methods from scratch in Matlab without making use of the stats toolbox, hence the above two questions.

Comment: try to only ask one question per thread

Comment: @Antoine They are both intimately related questions.  It would be a waste to make two separate questions.

Comment: Just an update, but I've decided to use a workaround and just iterate over all the feasible (n,c) and test if they satisfy the criteria specified.  This is quite slow, even for modest N and n.  I don't really consider this a solution, however, since it scales quite poorly for large lots and samples.